# Python numpy for loops, creating lists from lists and concatenating

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Python numpy list called my_list looking like the following which i can access the elements such as my_list[0] (first level) and my_list[0][0] (second level) and so on.

```
[array(['27103', '27106', '27104', '87115'],
       dtype='<U6'),
 array(['20049', '20033', '655155'],
       dtype='<U6'),...
```

For each element in the second level of the list i create another list with 3 elements each. So for the element "27103" there is a new list of length 3, for "27106" there is another list with 3 elements.

My question is how do I combine the new lists so that the calculation is done to the first level as well. I've written the code below:

```
temp_list = []
temp_list2 = []

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for j in range(len(set(my_list[i]))):
        temp_list.append(list(x[np.where(df.index.isin(my_list[i]))[0][j]]))
    temp_list2.append(np.concatenate(temp_list))
```

giving results such as:

```
[array(['111005', '112140', '627372', '639240', '672846', '71138', '10618',
        '110619', '639821', '668821', '672079', '672080'], dtype='<U6'),
 array(['111005', '112140', '627372', '639240', '672846', '71138', '10618',
        '110619', '639821', '668821', '672079', '672080', '109002',
        '112839', '26800', '112137', '652520', '667409', '104506',
        '110004', '110955'], dtype='<U6'),...
```

The problem is it appends to temp_list2 from the beginning. How can i prevent this and only take the relevant part such that it looks like the following?

```
[array(['111005', '112140', '627372', '639240', '672846', '71138', '10618',
        '110619', '639821', '668821', '672079', '672080'], dtype='<U6'),
 array(['109002', '112839', '26800', '112137', '652520', '667409', '104506',
        '110004', '110955'], dtype='<U6'),...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your desired output? The mapping of your input to your output is not clear to me.

Comment: Well that's exactly what you coded by `temp_list2.append(np.concatenate(temp_list))` inside the outer for loop. If you don't like that, then just don't concatenate and use the `temp_list2` instead.

Comment: You need to understand, that lists are **not** numpy ndarrays. And if you have numeric types (it looks like it, even though `dtype='<U6'` is set) and you already know the numer of elements after looping, only using numpy arrays is always a good idea.

Comment: Initialize one list inside the outer loop

Comment: @hpaulj exactly that was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this simply worked.

```
temp_list2 = []

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    temp_list = []
    for j in range(len(set(my_list[i]))):
        temp_list.append(list(x[np.where(df.index.isin(my_list[i]))[0][j]]))
    temp_list2.append(np.concatenate(temp_list))
```